# How am I supposed to find out what is the latest stable version of an npm package?

Tags: npm

How can I find the latest stable version of an npm package?

Other than going to http://search.npmjs.org and searching for it?

I usually need the version to put it in my `package.json`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `npm view [package-name] dist-tags` in the command line.

Example:

```
$ npm view express dist-tags

{ latest: '2.5.9',
  '3.0': '3.0.0beta2' }
```

Answer (score 11):

Since I had to google it myself:

After finding the specific version you want, install it using `npm install -g [package-name]@[your-version]`

Example:

```
$ npm view npm dist-tags

{ latest: '1.4.20',
  '1.4': '1.4.6',
  '1.2': '1.2.8000',
  'v1.5rc': '1.5.0-alpha-1' }

$  npm install -g npm@1.2
```

Comment: the question originally was how to find out the version, not how to install it

Comment: @ZerO correct, but I thought it might be helpful to some as it is a  natural path after listing dist versions