# NPM view most recent *stable* version of a package

Tags: node.js, npm

Instead of installing the latest version of an NPM package using

```
npm install x@latest
```

is there a way to *view* the latest *stable* version? something like this:

```
npm view x@stable version
```

I am looking for a programmatic/command line solution.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nodejs npm show latest version of a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949419/nodejs-npm-show-latest-version-of-a-module)

Comment: yeah I am looking for the latest *stable* version, if that's possible, not just the latest version

Comment: Ah right, my bad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How am I supposed to find out what is the latest stable version of an npm package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220598/how-am-i-supposed-to-find-out-what-is-the-latest-stable-version-of-an-npm-packag)

Comment: yeah that solution is not a complete programmatic solution, although I am not sure if there is one.

Comment: I think there's a programmatic solution in one of my old repos, now that I think about it. If I find it, I'll write up an answer.

Comment: ok cool thx that would be good

Answer (score 1):

Utilizing the following syntax returns the semver/value of the latest *stable* version only:

```
npm view <name> dist-tags.latest
```

You'll need to replace the `<name>` part with the actual package name.

**Example:**

```
npm view babel-cli dist-tags.latest
```

Running the command above currently prints `6.26.0` to the console, whilst the latest *non-stable* version available is the npm registry is currently `7.0.0-beta.3`

---

**Notes:**

The command above will report the same version which would get installed when running:

```
npm install <name>@latest
```

***Caveat:*** For either of the two commands to get the *truly stable* latest version they are reliant on the author/owner of the package having correctly managed their [dist-tags](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dist-tag). An excerpt from the docs *(at the link provided)* reads:

> Publishing a package sets the **`latest`** tag to the published version unless the **`--tag`** option is used. For example, **`npm publish --tag=beta`**.