# semver + latest with NPM dependencies

Tags: npm, semantic-versioning

A valid NPM dependency might look like:

```
dependencies:{
  "lodash":"latest"
}
```

but I use semver like this:

```
semver.eq('2.1.3','latest');
```

then I get:

```
TypeError: Invalid Version: latest
```

is there a way to handle 'latest' with semver or just ad-hoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to handle 'latest' with semver ....?

No, not using the [semver](https://github.com/npm/node-semver) package itself as it doesn't know what 'latest' is. Metadata stored in the npm registry associates 'latest' for a given package with a semver.

Consider shelling out the [npm-view](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view) command, using [`execSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) or [`exec()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback), to retrieve the 'latest' semver for the package in the npm registry **<sup>1</sup>**. Then pass the returned value as the second argument to the`semver.eq(...)` comparison.

For example:

```js
const semver = require('semver');
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

function getLatestVersion(pkg) {
  return JSON.parse(execSync(`npm view ${pkg} version --json`,
      { stdio: ['ignore', 'pipe', 'pipe'] }).toString());
}

const isEqual = semver.eq('2.1.3', getLatestVersion('lodash'));
console.log(isEqual); // --> false
```

---

1. <sub>As you know yourself from a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938391/npm-view-most-recent-stable-version-of-a-package). Exactly what the *'latest'* version resolves to, whether it's *'stable'*, *'alpha'*, *'beta'*, *'rc'*, etc can vary. However, if the package owner has correctly published updates it's most likely to be *'stable'*.</sub>